Building tensorflow serving failed wth following bazel errors
Building tensorflow serving from source failed wth following bazel errors
Don't get related issue or answer from google.
$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server 
$TEST_TMPDIR defined: output root default is '/home/work/serving/.cache' and max_idle_secs default is '15'.
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/BUILD:52:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/config': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:platform_config_util'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/BUILD:52:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:platform_config_util'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/core/BUILD:861:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/apis': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/core:stream_logger'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/BUILD:293:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/apis': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:http_rest_api_util'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/core/BUILD:23:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/util': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/core:servable_id'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/core/BUILD:753:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/config': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/core:log_collector'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/BUILD:293:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:http_rest_api_util'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/core/BUILD:775:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/apis': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/core:request_logger'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/core/BUILD:67:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/resources': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/core:loader'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/core/BUILD:127:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/util': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/core:target'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/core/BUILD:775:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/config': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/core:request_logger'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/core/BUILD:67:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/util': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/core:loader'
ERROR: /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/core/BUILD:817:11: error loading package 'tensorflow_serving/apis': at /home/work/serving/tensorflow_serving/serving.bzl:2:6: Label '@local_xla//xla/tsl/platform/default:build_config.bzl' is invalid because 'xla/tsl/platform/default' is not a package; perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@local_xla//xla/tsl:platform/default/build_config.bzl'? and referenced by '//tensorflow_serving/core:server_request_logger'


Can you add more details about how you're trying to build it? That might help people give you advice.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
